# Is $\mathbb{R}^4-\{0\}=S^3\times \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

In D. Bleecker's book "Gauge Theory and Variational Principles", he writes on p. 75 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{R}^4-\{0\} \simeq S^3\times \mathbb{R}
\end{equation} 
without further explanation. I would like to know why/if this is the case.

I know that a stereographic projection can send $S^n-p$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for $p$ some point of $S^n$) but I do not know the map that establishes the diffeomorphism above.

And if the above formular is right, how do you picture it? As a (3-)sphere which an infinitely thick shell?

Comment: For intuition, just think of adding a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ as a perpendicular line through each point of the sphere, ending at the origin.

Comment: Polar coordinates.

Comment: @Thomas alright, that is what I meant with the infinitely thick shell, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to picture it is $\Bbb R^n\setminus \{0\} =\bigcup_{r>0} \Bbb S^{n-1}(0,r)$, but you need to fix up the radii since he is using $\Bbb S^{n-1}\times \Bbb R$ instead of $\Bbb S^{n-1}\times \Bbb R_{>0}$. The map $$\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}\ni x\mapsto \left(\frac{x}{\|x\|},\log \|x\|\right)\in \Bbb S^{n-1}\times \Bbb R $$does the magic.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb{R}^4\setminus\{0\}&\longrightarrow&S^3\times\mathbb{R}\\v&\mapsto&\left(\frac v{\|v\|},\log\|v\|\right).\end{array}$$